Job with shareIdentifier or schedulingPriority can onlybe submitted to job queue with fair share scheduling policy
I have created a AWS Batch job definition, queue. When I submit a job using the CMD, I got the following error message.
Job with shareIdentifier or schedulingPriority can onlybe submitted to job queue with fair share scheduling policy.

Here is my job definition,

{
  "jobDefinitionName": "learning-job-definition",
  "jobDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:0xxxxxxxxxx5:job-definition/learning-job-definition:2",
  "revision": 2,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "type": "container",
  "schedulingPriority": 1,
  "parameters": {},
  "retryStrategy": {
    "attempts": 2,
    "evaluateOnExit": []
  },
  "containerProperties": {
    "image": "0xxxxxxxxxx5.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/learnings:latest",
    "command": [],
    "jobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::0xxxxxxxxxx5:role/service-roles/axxxxxx-legacy-dev-vp-GzipperAWSBatchService-zjTK9JzNEbGZ",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::0xxxxxxxxxx5:role/service-roles/axxxxxx-legacy-dev-vp-GzipperAWSBatchService-zjTK9JzNEbGZ",
    "volumes": [],
    "environment": [],
    "mountPoints": [],
    "readonlyRootFilesystem": true,
    "ulimits": [],
    "user": "test",
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {
        "value": "1.0",
        "type": "VCPU"
      },
      {
        "value": "2048",
        "type": "MEMORY"
      }
    ],
    "secrets": [],
    "networkConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED",
      "interfaceConfigurations": []
    },
    "fargatePlatformConfiguration": {
      "platformVersion": "LATEST"
    },
    "ephemeralStorage": {
      "sizeInGiB": 21
    },
    "runtimePlatform": {
      "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX",
      "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64"
    }
  },
  "timeout": {
    "attemptDurationSeconds": 600
  },
  "tags": {
    "Project": "axxxxxx",
    "Sub Project": "SharedaxxxxxxResource"
  },
  "platformCapabilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "containerOrchestrationType": "ECS"
}

CMD
aws batch submit-job --job-name test-local-write-2 --job-definition learning-job-definition --job-queue learning-queue --scheduling-policy fair-share


I couldn't find similar issues online and there is no clear documentation on how to use shareIdentifier or schedulingPriority.

I found the mistake, it seems mentioning schedulingPriority in the JobDefinition will require Scheduling policy need to be added in the Job Queue.
In my case, I don't need the schedulingPriority, so after removing that from Job definition everything is working as expected.

You need to create a scheduling policy if it doesn't exist in your case named (fair-share) if already created enable it at the job queue :
aws batch update-job-queue --job-queue learning-queue --scheduling-policy-arn arn:aws:batch:<region>:<account-id>:scheduling-policy/fair-share


There are two types of job queues in AWS Batch:

First in first out - this is the default and does not need either share ID or scheduling priority. By default, job queues are FIFO.
Fair share - these are meant to balance usage of available compute resources  across different share IDs via an attached scheduling policy. See this blog post for how they work. Share priority will working within a single share ID, not across shares.

AWS Batch documentation on the types of queues here.
